# NullPointerException with while loop using compareTo

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, compareto, doubly-linked-list

For our homework, I have to take in `Chair` objects and add them to the `DoublyLinkedList` that we made; it has to be sorted by alphabetical order, if style is the same alphabetically, we sort by color

When I try to go through the loop, I keep getting a `NullPointerException`.

```
public void add(Chair element){
    if(isEmpty() || first.object.style.compareTo(element.style) > 0 || (first.object.style.compareTo(element.style) == 0 && first.object.color.compareTo(element.color) >= 0){
        addFirst(element);
    }else if(first.object.style.compareTo(element.style) <= 0){
        Node temp = first;
        Node insert = new Node(); insert.object = element;
        while(temp.object.style.compareTo(element.style) <= 0) //This is where the nullPointerException occurs
            if(temp.hasNext())
                temp = temp.next;
        while(temp.object.style.compareTo(element.style) == 0 && temp.object.color.compareTo(element.color) <= 0)
            if(temp.hasNext())
                temp = temp.next;
        insert.prev = temp.prev;
        insert.next = temp;
        temp.prev.next = insert;
        temp.prev = insert;
    }
}
```

This is the code where I put the information into the DoublyLinkedList

```
try{
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(filename);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(fr);
        String[] temp;

        while(sc.hasNext()){
            temp = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
            if(temp[0].equals("Bed")){}
            else if(temp[0].equals("Table")){
            //  tables.add(new Table(Integer.parseInt(temp[1]), Integer.parseInt(temp[2]), Integer.parseInt(temp[3]), temp[4]));
            }else if(temp[0].equals("Desk")){}
            else if(temp[0].equals("Chair")){
                chairs.add(new Chair(temp[1], temp[2]));
            }else if(temp[0].equals("Bookshelves")){}
            else{
                color = temp[0];
            }
        }
        while(!chairs.isEmpty())
            System.out.println(chairs.removeFirst().info());
        System.out.println();
        //while(!tables.isEmpty())
        //  System.out.println(tables.removeFirst().info());
    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

This is the DoublyLinkedList class that I've made:
class CDoublyLinkedList{
    Node first, last;

```
public CDoublyLinkedList(){
    first = new Node(); last = new Node();
    first.prev = last.next = null;
    first.object = last.object = null;
    first.next = last;
    last.prev = first;
}

public boolean isEmpty(){
    return first.object == null;
}

public void addFirst(Chair element){
    Node insert = new Node();
    insert.object = element;
    insert.prev = null;
    insert.next = first;
    first.prev = insert;
    first = insert;
}

public void add(Chair element){
    if(isEmpty() || first.object.style.compareTo(element.style) > 0 || (first.object.style.compareTo(element.style) == 0 && first.object.color.compareTo(element.color) >= 0){
        addFirst(element);
    }else if(first.object.style.compareTo(element.style) <= 0){
        Node temp = first;
        Node insert = new Node(); insert.object = element;
        while(first.object.style.compareTo(element.style) <= 0)
            if(temp.hasNext())
                temp = temp.next;
        while(first.object.style.compareTo(element.style) == 0 && first.object.color.compareTo(element.color) <= 0)
            if(temp.hasNext())
                temp = temp.next;
        insert.prev = temp.prev;
        insert.next = temp;
        temp.prev.next = insert;
        temp.prev = insert;
    }
}

public Chair removeFirst(){
    Chair tobedeleted = first.object;
    Node temp = first.next;
    first = temp;
    first.prev = null;
    return tobedeleted;
}

private class Node{
    Node next, prev;
    Chair object;
    public boolean hasNext(){
        return next != null;
    }
}
```

}

The Chair class:

```
class Chair extends Furniture{
public String style, color;
public Chair(String s, String c){
    style = s; color = c;
}
public String toString(){
    return color;
}
public String getType(){
    return "Chair";
}
public String info(){
    return (color+", "+style);
}
 }
```

Can someone please explain to me why I keep getting this error? Thank you!

EDIT:

```
while(temp.object.style.compareTo(element.style) <= 0) //This is where the nullPointerException occurs

chairs.add(new Chair(temp[1], temp[2]));

java.lang.NullPointerException
at CDoublyLinkedList.add(Furnish2SS.java:119)
at Furnish2SS.main(Furnish2SS.java:23)
java.lang.NullPointerException
at CDoublyLinkedList.add(Furnish2SS.java:119)
at Furnish2SS.main(Furnish2SS.java:23)
```

EDIT2: SOLVED!

I changed my while loop to:

```
while(temp.object != null && element != null && (temp.object.compareTo(element) == 0 || temp.object.compareTo(element) == -1))
```

The reason I got the error was because I wasn't checking for `null` every iteration.

Comment: one or many of your inner objects seem to be null first  or object or style try putting the loop in a try catch to get the inner exception

Comment: You're getting the error because something is null. To find out what, look at the stacktrace and see what line it says the exception occurred on.

Comment: There is an object that is being referred to in the project that hasn't been instantiated or is set to null. Debug the program and please tell us which line your error is found in. This might even help YOU solve your own problem.

Comment: Can you post your stack trace?

Comment: for your Information, things like `first.object.style.` are not the best code practice. It works, but using private fields with getters and setters gives you more control about who can access certain variables and what someone can write in them

Comment: I posted the stack trace. I also made the variables private and made a compareTo in the Chair class to compare instead of manually comparing.

Comment: Also, the code ends up printing the remove's either way after it prints out the exception

Comment: Just some little sidenotes on your list implementation (has nothing to do with the error, I already made a comments regarding that on Mike Clark's anwer): Suppose you have a `Chair c`. Now you add `c` 1 mio. times to your list (for whatever reason). If you now add it again, that will take quite some time even though there's a very fast way of adding it. Oh and I think there's a second error in your list class. Have you tried adding a `Chair` to a non-empty list, that is supposed to appear at the and of the list? As far as I can tell, that shouldn't work. I hope these hints are helpfull.

Comment: Regarding that last part: That only happens, if you use the 3rd code you posted. Did you notice that your first and your third code are different? The one uses `while(tmp....)` the other while(`first....)`. I just noticed why I wasn't able to reproduce your exception. I copied over your whole class code. There the Exception isn't thrown. If you use the version with `while(tmp....)` however, it is.

Answer (score 2):

You say this is the line of code causing the exception:

```
while(temp.object.style.compareTo(element.style) <= 0)
```

You probably should set a debugger breakpoint on that line and use a debugger to determine which of the values is null. But it's hard for me to explain here full instructions on how to setup and use a debugger (that doesn't mean you shouldn't learn!  You should.  There are lots of tutorials.  Google it.)  So instead of writing a tutorial on debuggers, I'll just post code that will tell you which variable is null:

```
if (temp == null) {
    System.out.println("temp is null");
} else if (temp.object == null) {
    System.out.println("temp.object is null");
} else if (temp.object.style == null) {
    System.out.println("temp.object.style is null");
} 

if (element == null) {
    System.out.println("element is null");
} else if (element.style == null) {
    System.out.println("element.style is null");
}


while(temp.object.style.compareTo(element.style) <= 0) //This is where the nullPointerException occurs
{
    if(temp.hasNext())
        temp = temp.next;

    if (temp == null) {
        System.out.println("loop: temp is null");
    } else if (temp.object == null) {
        System.out.println("loop: temp.object is null");
    } else if (temp.object.style == null) {
        System.out.println("loop: temp.object.style is null");
    } 

    if (element == null) {
        System.out.println("loop: element is null");
    } else if (element.style == null) {
        System.out.println("loop: element.style is null");
    }

}
```

If you use the above code statements to replace these three lines of your code:

```
    while(temp.object.style.compareTo(element.style) <= 0) //This is where the nullPointerException occurs
        if(temp.hasNext())
            temp = temp.next;
```

you will know which variable is null based on which statement is printed.  Hopefully you can take it from there.  (The usual way to fix a NullPointerException is to take the steps necessary to ensure the offending null variable actually has a valid, non-null value by the time the program reaches the line of the NullPointerException).

Comment: The thing is, I just put this all in a try-catch and even though it throws an exception, the code in the while-loop works. I also tried to check for "temp == null" and nothing printed out.

Comment: I fixed it. For some reason the code runs fine but the NullPointerException is thrown. I just took out the stack trace and it prints out the information just as I want it.

Comment: @prunes4u that is not fixed, that is an ugly hack!  Take some pride in your work and don't use try{}catch{} with no print to hide errors which shouldn't be in your program! :)  If I were your teacher I'd mark you down for submitting code which throws errors during normal operation.  Tough love! :)

Comment: I tried checking for "temp == null", "element == null", and "temp.object == null". None of them printed out the message, so I have no idea what is throwing the null. Also, since it throws and exception, the code in the loop shouldn't run, but it does.

Comment: Well, then all that's left is `temp.object.style`. The only things that could be `null` are `temp.object` and `temp.object.style` anyways.

Comment: check those as well. Still throwing it.

Comment: Can you just copy/paste my code into your code?  Use my lines to replace your 3 lines like I described in the answer?

Comment: I did, didn't work. BUT, I did figure out why it didn't work. I changed the while to: while(temp.object != null && element != null && (temp.object.compareTo(element) == 0 || temp.object.compareTo(element) == -1)), and I don't get a nullPointer ever

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `addFirst(Chair element)`. That method is really screwed up. It creates a new `Node` which contains the correct `Chair`. It then sets its `prev` to `null`. Then it sets `next` to `first`. And this is what's causing all of your troubles. Because `first` points to an empty `Node`. You end up with this:

`first` points to your new `Node`. That one points to a `Node` which holds no `Chair`. That one again points to `last`.

e:

Your whole code looks like you had at least two different approaches on implementing your list and threw them toghether. There are some more errors but since this is homework I guess it's not that bad if you try fixing it first.

If you can't figure out how to correct that, ask here.

PS: Sorry for all of the editing and (un)deleting my answeres (if you noticed). I'm a bit tired and kept causing new errors by fixing old ones until I finally figured out what was the true cause of all this.

Comment: +1 for actually helping him with the logic of his code.  I wasn't brave enough!